# Displaced Xcode text on file new project

Tags: xcode, development, macos

[image]

As you can see from the image. the text is displaced. The app is running normal and no indication of any damage.
It is not affecting the functionality, but it is very annoying.
How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 is not supported in macOS Sierra. You should use the Xcode 8 beta from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/).